# How to integrate constant contact api in desktop application?

Tags: asp.net, constantcontact

I am trying to integrate constant contact service in my .net desktop application. What to set redirect URL for desktop application?

Comment: if i understand correctly `app.config` is the solution

Answer (score 0):

In an OAuth 2.0 flow where you are using a Client Application (such as a .net desktop app, mobile app or anything else that is not a SaaS application), the value of the redirect URI doesn't tend to matter as long as it is in the valid URI format supported by the vendor.  With the Client Flow of OAuth 2.0 ([see here for more information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4)), you would open up a web browser in your application, load the OAuth grant access flow and watch for a 302 redirect to your predetermined redirect URI.  When you see that redirect, you would intercept it instead of loading that page in the web browser your application loaded and then pull the authorization code off of the URI fragment.

Simply follow the follow up flow for exchanging the authorization code for the access token, save the access token in the local application settings for future use and you're all set.  This is standard for all OAuth 2.0 providers, not just Constant Contact.  In .Net, I tend to use a [WebView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) to load the flow in the application.